# Common Factor in Matrices?

Tags: matrices

I am trying to solve some matrix multiplications, but I would like to know If I am allowed to take a common factor from matrices like this

```
C - ABC = (1 - AB)*C
```

where A is m*n and B is n*n. And if yes, what matrix will be the 1 matrix? It cannot be an identity as the AB is m*n.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write $C-ABC=(I-AB)C$ with $I$ the identity matrix (a matrix with zeroes off-diagonal and ones on the main diagonal) all day long as long as $C-ABC$ makes sense.

To see this, suppose that $C$ is a matrix with $m$ rows and $n$ columns.  Then $A$ must have $m$ rows and $B$ must have $m$ columns because otherwise $C-ABC$ would not make sense.  So $AB$ is necessarily square and you can compute the difference $I-AB$.

Answer (score 0):

If $AB$ is not square (e.g. if it is $m\times n$ with $m \not = n$) then the subtraction in your original expression will not work as $C$ and $ABC$ will have different dimensions.

Comment: Therefore I cannot take a common factor?

Comment: If you do not have a meaningful expression, then you cannot do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not factor first? $C = IC$ with $I$ square and same dimension as number of rows for $C$. From there regardless of all other dimensions, as long as your original equation makes sense and has conformable dimensions, then YES there is the common factor that can be factored:
$$C - ABC$$
$$IC - ABC$$
$$(I - AB)C$$

Comment: If the factored equation does not make sense, then your original must be wrong. $C$ is $m \times p$ because it has the same rows as $A$ in $C - ABC$ else the subtraction cannot be done. $C$ is $n \times p$ since $B$ is $n \times n$ and $BC$ is part of the equation. Thus you have $n = m$ and the square identity makes sense and is also necessary for your equation.